# I am having a blank page with ReactJS - I am new just starting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the default installation when installing Reactjs on ubuntu server, then initiating an app.
So in ./public/index.html in this file I have a location called root to where the index.js file (its content below) inserts the Reactjs code shown below.

the default screen of the reactjs on port 3000 that shows the react logo, now shows blank white page.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import './index.css';
// import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


class component1Class extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return <h1>  hello world  </h1>;
            return <h1>hello world</h1>;
            return <h1>hello world</h1>;
            return <h1>hello world</h1>;
      }
      };


ReactDOM.render(<component1Class />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: it’s hard to understand what’s the problem here: please, provide more information and use the Markdown syntax on code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components must start with a capital letter. Change `component1Class` to `Component1Class`. You can also only return once in a component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Component1Class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Component1Class />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this little change has totally solved it, I reinstalled everything thinking babel or something was missing, and nothing solved it, then did this little change and it worked.. Many thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned, you can only return once. I'll update my question so that it returns "hello world" 4 times.